# What are tf.TensorArray objects?

Tags: tensorflow

I am not able to get an understanding of [tf.TensorArray](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) objects. What are they and where are they needed? I have some (highly likely faulty) understanding -
 they are used in while_loops especially to write the information to the loop_state. If somehow we end up increasing the number of tensors or their dimensions across iterations it throws back an error. hence normal way to pass the loop_state across iterations collecting information from each iteration, which would be passing a list, would throw back an error. So we create tf.TensorArray objects and write the information to them at each iteration and pass these tf.TensorArray objects across loops and for some reason that way it is able to pass through

I couldnt find any blog or documentation explaining the working of a tf.TensorArray objects and documentation doesn't help much either

So, if this is not the best place to be asking this question, kindly direct me to nearest help.